# How can I change the language preference in .bashrc file

Tags: language-support

How can I set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in .bashrc? When I looked into .bashrc, I can't find any LANG settings.

Comment: Do you have a desktop or a server?

Comment: Does the answer solve you problem?!

Answer (score 9):

```
gedit .bashrc
```

then put these lines in your ~/.bashrc

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

To make these changes active in the current shell, source the .bashrc:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: The value you assign to LANGUAGE is plain wrong. LANGUAGE expects a list of colon separated language codes without the '.UTF-8' part. Also, why do you suggest that both LC_ALL and LANG are set?

Comment: In case of LANGUAGE i believe it works as though also. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/changing-default-language-from-command-line-438947/  http://wangpidong.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-set-locale-environment-variables.html

Comment: LC_ALL used to override any LC_* such as  LC_MESSAGES, LC_PAPER, LC_NAME, LC_ADDRESS, LC_TELEPHONE....

Comment: Hmm.. I stand corrected as regards LANGUAGE values. When testing I found that it seems to recognize "language codes" which consist of locale names including '.UTF-8'. That's indeed useful to know. Thanks!

LC_ALL overrides LANG as well. Typically it's used [within programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html#Locale-Environment-Variables) rather than in the session environment.

On a desktop, setting these variables in .bashrc screws up the GUIs for handling languages and locales. That's why I asked the OP if he has a desktop or a server.